# How to retrieve specific text from a string in C#?

Tags: c#, string, browser, web

I'm working on a Windows Application (C#) made a web bot using web browser. I sent data successfully but when I retrieve, I used this line of code:

```
string Data = webBotB.Document.GetElementById("page").InnerText;
```

Data is contain too much useless text.

Now, My question is how to collect (pick-up) specific data (some text) in between Data knowing the words before and after the desired text, in order to make it appear on a label on the Win App?

I think my question is almost related to String methods but if there is a solution to retrieve data more specific and easily than the method wrote above from Web Browser, I appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) and [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method to do what you need.

```
string Between(string data, string start, string end)
{
    int startIndex = data.IndexOf(start) + start.Length;
    int endIndex = data.IndexOf(end, startIndex);
    return data.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
}
```

Call it like this:

```
Between("JohnDoeHelloFoobarGoodbyeStackOverflow", "Hello", "Goodbye")
// "Foobar"
```

Note: This method does not handle cases where either of the strings are not found.

Comment: Thanks Efex! :)
Frey, your method did what I wanted. Thank You very much :)

Comment: @BasimHennawi If this answered your question, please mark it as the correct answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.